# Coordinates out of Bounds while setting values in WritableRaster

Tags: java, image-processing, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm doing a program on median filter. All i'm trying to accomplish is taking one pixel value, finding its neighboring pixels, and storing them in an array , sorting that array, and taking the middle value (for array of size 9 middle value is index position 4). and substituting this value at exactly same coordinates as the pixel under consideration.

the loops work fine if i remove its content and just print the values of `i,j,x,y`. The moment I add the statement wherein i do `neighborhoodVal.add(imageRaster.getSample(x, y, 0));` i get a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds!` error.

From what I observed, I found that the value of `j` becomes `1`when value of `i` becomes `264`, its strange, since I loop all the pixels only within the image, the outer two loops (i and j) loop through all the pixels except those at the edges of the image. and the inner loops (`x` & `y`) loop through all 8 neighbors of the `[i][j]`th pixel.

The image i'm using has `width = 265` and `height=269`.
the code is as follows:

```
public class MedianFilter {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int i, j, x, y;
        ArrayList<Integer> neighborhoodVal = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ;
        String imagePath = "images/assignment10/noisyShapes.jpg";
        BufferedImage inputImage = convertToGrayScale(ImageIO.read(new File(
                imagePath)));
        WritableRaster imageRaster = inputImage.getRaster();
        BufferedImage filteredImage = new BufferedImage(inputImage.getWidth(),
                inputImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        WritableRaster newWRaster = filteredImage.getRaster();



        for (i = 1; i < imageRaster.getHeight()-1; i++) {
            for (j = 1; j < imageRaster.getWidth()-1; j++) {
                for (x = Math.max(0, i - 1); x <= Math.min(i + 1,imageRaster.getWidth()); x++) {
                    for (y = Math.max(0, j - 1); y <= Math.min(j + 1,imageRaster.getHeight()); y++) {
                        
                        System.out.println(i+","+j+"------->"+x+","+y);
                        
                        neighborhoodVal.add(imageRaster.getSample(x, y, 0));
                        Collections.sort(neighborhoodVal);
                    }
                }
                newWRaster.setSample(i, j, 0, (neighborhoodVal
                                .get((neighborhoodVal.size() / 2) + 1)));
                neighborhoodVal.clear();
            }

        }

        File f = new File("images/assignment10/medianFilterOutput.jpg");
        ImageIO.write(filteredImage, "JPG", f);

    }
    public static BufferedImage convertToGrayScale(BufferedImage givenImage)
            throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(givenImage.getWidth(),
                givenImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
        Graphics grp = image.getGraphics();
        grp.drawImage(givenImage, 0, 0, null);
        return image;
    }
}
```

and I'm using this image:

[image]

How does `j` become 1? Where am I going wrong in this?

Comment: In the inner loop it looks like you might be searching beyond the edge of the image by using "x <= Math.min(i + 1,imageRaster.getWidth())" instead of "... x <= imageRaster.getWidth() - 1".

Comment: @Rethunk i tried doing that, the problem still persists

Comment: Oops, that wasn't it at all. I think I found the problem, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the outer loop you're using "i" with .getHeight(), but in the inner loop "x" is used with .getWidth(). So it looks like the bounds for i and j need to be swapped. It's probably a typo from tiredness; I might well do it myself in the sample code below.

Also, since the outer loops already ignore border pixels, the inner loops could just be "for(x = i - 1; i <= i + 1; i++" and "for(y = j - 1; y <= j + 1; j++)" and be guaranteed to be within bounds.

And if I might make a recommendation: in image processing it's conventional to scan row by row (that is, by "y")in the outermost loop, then by x, and also to use (x,y) for pixel coordinates and (i,j) for offsets. For example:

```
int r = 1;  //radius, in case you want to use median over a larger kernel

for(int y = r; y < height - r; y++)
{
   for (int x = r; x < width - r; x++)
   {
      for(int j = y - r; j <= y + r; j++)
      {
         for(i = x - r; i <= x + r; i++)
         {
            //get all neighborhood values 
         } 
      }    

      //find median
   }
}
```

That said, once you use a convention, stick to it. Accidentally swapping the getWidth() and getHeight() bounds is easy, but if you always nest your loops in the same order of y,x,j,i you'll be a bit more likely to type the correct bounds without thinking about it.